# Declaring app as not an AccessibilityTool to comply with google play requirements

Tags: android, google-play-console, accessibilityservice, android-12

When targeting Android SDK (31), google play requires us to specify the `isAccessibilityTool` attribute in our app, if the app is not an accessibility tool then you have to declare that in your app, but where to?

If we haven't declared that in you the app google presume that you are using `AccessibilityService` API

> If you have not declared your app to be an accessibility tool but use the AccessibilityService API, i.e. you have not set the `isAccessibilityTool` flag in your accessibility service’s metadata file, you will be required to complete an accessibility declaration in Play Console. [source](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9214102)

Google Play Console now requires me to fill a form of why I am using `AccessibilityService` (which my app does not use) when I am targeting Android 12.

To give more details to the issue here are some images from Google Console:
[image: 1]
[image: 2]

I tried to create a service of `AccessibilityService` and in metadata to set `isAccessibilityTool` to `false`, but still google won't let me update the app till I fill the Accessibility services form:

```kotlin
class MyAccessibilityService: AccessibilityService() {
    override fun onAccessibilityEvent(event: AccessibilityEvent?) {}
    override fun onInterrupt() {}
}
```

Here is the service declaration in the AndroidManifest file:

```xml
<service
  android:name=".MyAccessibilityService"
  android:exported="true">
  <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
  </intent-filter>
  <meta-data
     android:name="android.accessibilityservice"
     android:resource="@xml/serviceconfig" />
</service>
```

Here is the content of serviceconfig file:

```xml
<accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:isAccessibilityTool="false"
    android:packageNames="com.example.my_package"
    tools:targetApi="s" />
```

Am I missing out on something? Where or How to declare the `isAccessibilityTool` attribute to till the Console this is the app not use the `AccessibilityService` API?

**Update**

I tried to include the service metadata directly in the application tag:

```xml
<application
   ...>
<meta-data
     android:name="android.accessibilityservice"
     android:resource="@xml/serviceconfig" />
</application>
```

Also, I tried to use the `isAccessibilityTool` attribute directly in the application tag:

```xml
<application
....
 tools:targetApi="s"
 android:isAccessibilityTool="false">
</application>
```

non of the above worked for me

**Final update**

I checked the merged manifest and one of the services contains this permission:

```xml
android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE"
```

I only removed this line and worked (thanks to [Snorlax](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5595926/snorlax) for his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70331922/6470661) google play no more is asking me tool fill the form why I'm using `AccessibilityService` API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you check the merged AndroidManifest? Maybe it's a library or module accessing the `AccessibilityService` API, you have to remove the following lines if they exist in your app AndroidManifest, if don't want to fill the Google Play usage accessibility form:

```xml
<intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
</intent-filter>
```

Also, check that you're not requesting permission for an accessibility service by accident in one of your services in the AndroidManifest:

```xml
android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE"
```

and probably you don't need to use the `isAccessibilityTool` attribute.

Comment: Thanks but I'm not trying to create an AccessibilityService, I only need to mark my app as not an AccessibilityTool so I google accept my update, I updated the question please read it again and take a look at the source link

Comment: In fact, if you read the question carefully you can see that I already tried to create an accessibility service

Comment: Can you check the merged manifest? Maybe it's using a library.

Comment: Snorlax that did work I checked my app and of the services has
android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE"
I didn't notice it was there until you said to check the merged manifest

Comment: Thank you. I think I deserve the point. I updated my answer. :)
It will be enough to add it to the relevant service. android:isAccessibilityTool="false"

Comment: Yep, you deserve the points, but your answer generally is describing how to create an accessibility service while this is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: One more thing for being transparent, adding to the service ```android:isAccessibilityTool="false"``` didn't work google still requires me to fill form why I need AccessibilityTool.

Comment: the only thing that worked is removing this line from the service
```android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE"```

Please update your answer to contain only the relevant info.

Answer (score 4):

You can declare that in the manifest file's application tag of your Accessibility service

```
 <application...
 ...
 android:isAccessibilityTool="false"
 ...
 .. >

 ... />
```

OR

as an attribute to your service, your code will be

```
<service
 android:name=".MyAccessibilityService"
 android:exported="true"
 android:isAccessibilityTool="false">
 <intent-filter>
 <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" 
 />
 </intent-filter>
 <meta-data
 android:name="android.accessibilityservice"
 android:resource="@xml/serviceconfig" />
 </service>
```

If you set isAccessibilityTool="false", but still use the service, you would need to complete the declaration on google play conbsole.

Check this for more details [Declaration for apps that are NOT accessibility tools](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10964491?hl=en)

Comment: I already tried to declare it as an attribute to the service, but I'll try to put it in the application tag directly --- Thanks

Comment: oh cool then, let's see if this works

Comment: same google play won't let me update my app

Comment: it is becoming furstrating

Comment: please check this,  (https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10964491?hl=en) Declaration for apps that are NOT accessibility tools. You need to tell google why your app is using this service but its not an accessibility tool.

Comment: this is sally thing that I am not even using the service in my app

Comment: Gouse, please read the quoted statement in the question

Comment: you have named your service android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService

Comment: I just have created the service for trying out if it will work, no it didn't and Later I removed it